# Maven obfuscation with ProGuard

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, proguard

I have recently created a JAR file that needs obfuscation, but I cannot seem to get it working what so ever. Either it throws a bunch of warnings about not found references, duplications or it just doesn't obfuscate anything at all. I'm using the Maven Proguard plugin.

Maven build log: https://hastebin.com/oneyozizoh.hs
It says build succeed but it is not what I'm looking for: it does not include the external dependencies (influxDB) and it's not even obfuscated.

Here's the deal:

- It uses external libraries such as InfluxDB. This needs to be included in JAR upon exporting. The plugin will not work without it. These external libs should not be obfuscated (unless there's a way to obfuscate every single required dependency as well and still have it work).
- It also uses some other JAR files as optional dependencies (scope system or provided). These are NOT included in the export JAR. These libraries should not be obfuscated what so ever as they are resolved at runtime (if present).

It would most likely be the easiest if only my project package gets obfuscated, which is `com.dyescape.*`. I have tried this but I cannot seem to get it working.

Here is the pom.xml file I have so far.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dyescape</groupId>
  <artifactId>ServerStatistics</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>ServerStatistics</name>
  <description>A plugin that gathers server statistics and pushes them to an external panel.</description>
  <url>https://www.dyescape.com</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spigot-repo</id>
      <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vault-repo</id>
        <url>http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>viaversion-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.viaversion.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>votifier-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.howaner.de/com/vexsoftware/votifier/1.9/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>minebuilders-repo</id>
        <url>http://minebuilders.me:8080/plugin/repository/everything/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <!--Spigot API-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
                <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.MassiveCraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>MassiveCore</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/MassiveCore.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.MassiveCraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>Factions</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/Factions.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.leoko.advancedban</groupId>
        <artifactId>AdvancedBan</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/AdvancedBan.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.neatmonster.nocheatplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>NoCheatPlus</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.1-RC-sMD5NET-b1084</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/NoCheatPlus.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>us.myles</groupId>
        <artifactId>viaversion</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>1.2.0-17w31a-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vexsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>votifier</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/Votifier.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gmail.nossr50</groupId>
        <artifactId>mcMMO</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.08-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/mcMMO.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.konsolas</groupId>
        <artifactId>aac</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-b1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/AAC.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>PAC</groupId>
        <artifactId>PAC</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/PAC.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.Keyle</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyPet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/MyPet.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.minebuilders</groupId>
        <artifactId>clearlag-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        <!-- Resources -->
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- Keeping filtering at true here reduces plugin.yml redundancy! -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- Keep filtering at false for other resources to prevent bad magic -->
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>plugin.yml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.3.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>5.3.3</proguardVersion>
                    <options>
                        <option>-dontshrink</option>
                        <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                        <option>-keep class !com.dyescape.**,com.dyescape.serverstatistics.ServerStatistics { *; }</option>
                        <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod,*Annotations*</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The command I used to use to build the JAR (including required dependencies) is the following:

```
clean package assembly:single
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Alright, removed the "urgent" part. Can you help me with the question though?

Comment: Not me, no - not my area. Please don't add chatty material to questions though, [we remove that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Incidentally, I notice your question does not mention what problems you are getting - do you get any errors when you try this? Please add them to the Q if you have some.

Comment: Regarding your new update, is it worth adding some of the "bunch of warnings" to your question? Perhaps they will be useful to a reader that could help.

Comment: I did state that they were warnings about duplication or missing references, but I will provide the full build log if it helps out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, thanks - I don't know if it will help, but it's better to have it in, when in doubt.